# SQLite ISO (ie European style) week numbers

Tags: sqlite, numbers, iso, strftime

I want to return ISO standard week numbers (ie week 1-52/53) from a date.
I have tried using the built in function strftime, but with no success.

Can anyone suggest a way without having to write a custom C or other function.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but recently I was looking for an efficient solution for the same problem, and this is what I came up with:

```
SELECT
    my_date,
    (strftime('%j', date(my_date, '-3 days', 'weekday 4')) - 1) / 7 + 1 as iso_week
FROM my_table;
```

The basic idea is to calculate the ISO week number by simply performing integer division of the day of year of the Thursday of the date being looked up (my_date) by 7, giving a result between 0 and 52, and then adding 1 to it. And the subtraction by 1 just before the division is there just for the alignment of the division: Thursday of week 1, for example, can have a day of year between 1 and 7, and we want the result of the division to be 0 in all cases, so we need to subtract 1 from the day of year before dividing it by 7.

Comment: So, first off, this is really great ... however ... this doesn't give you the YEAR portion in addition to the iso week.

For example:
```select (strftime('%j', date('2006-01-01', '-3 days', 'weekday 4')) - 1) / 7 + 1 as iso_week
```

should result in the following iso week date 2005-W52-7

Answer (score 0):

What specifically did you try?
This works for me (using built-in SQLite from Python REPL):

```
import sqlite3
c = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c.execute('''create table t (c);''')
c.execute('''insert into t values ('2012-01-01');''')
c.execute('''select c, strftime('%W',c) from t;''').fetchone()
# -> (u'2012-01-01', u'00')
```

Comment: Adam, thanks for the feedback, but isn't '%w' to get day number of week?

Comment: @user1224125: Indeed! I updated the example with the correct constant.

Comment: Thanks anyway, but didnt seem to work for me.... came up with the solution below....

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I managed to answer my own question. For anyone who might need a similar solution, this is what I came up with. Please note, I do not have an IT background and my SQL is self taught.

### General process

1. Get the Thursday of the week the date belongs too.
2. Get the 4th of January of the year of that Thursday.
3. Get the Thursday of the week the 4th January date belongs too.
4. Subtract Step 2 with Step 3, divide by 7 and add 1.

Translated into SQLite....

```
SELECT
date,
CASE CAST (strftime('%w', wknumjanfourth) AS INTEGER)
  WHEN 0 THEN ((JULIANDAY(datesThur) - JULIANDAY(strftime("%s", wknumjanfourth) - 259200, 'unixepoch')) / 7) + 1   
  ELSE ((JULIANDAY(datesThur) - JULIANDAY(DATE(strftime("%s", wknumjanfourth) - (86400 * (strftime('%w', wknumjanfourth) - 1)), 'unixepoch'), '+3 day')) / 7) + 1
END AS weeknum
FROM
(
  SELECT
  date,
  datesThur,
  DATE(datesThur,'start of year','+3 day') AS wknumjanfourth
  FROM
  (SELECT 
    date,
    CASE CAST (strftime('%w', date) AS INTEGER)
      WHEN 0 THEN DATE(strftime("%s", date) - 259200, 'unixepoch')
      ELSE DATE(DATE(strftime("%s", date) - (86400 * (strftime('%w', date) - 1)), 'unixepoch'), '+3 day')
      END AS datesThur
   FROM TEST
))
```

If anyone can improve this SQL, I would appreciate the feedback.